# Just out of curitosity: Would anyone closer to UTC+8 be interested in becoming a diamond moderator?

Tags: discussion, moderation

It was agreed on Meta that we'd wait a while before our next election: [We had an election relatively recently, shall we keep our current moderation team for a bit longer?](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/305/5)

My opinion on that has not changed, in fact it's been fortified. However, I'm also curious if anyone closer to [UTC+8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B08:00) would be interested in helping with diamond moderation of this site?

The reason I ask is because two of our diamond moderators currently live in the [Western Hemisphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Hemisphere) and ***only one*** lives in the [Eastern Hemisphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Hemisphere).

Tyberius is in UTC-5 and Camps is in UTC-3, the average being UTC-4. When it's 1am in UTC-4, where is it 1pm? UTC+8. Also considering that UTC+8 is the time zone such that: "With an estimated population of 1.708 billion living within the time zone, roughly 24% of the world population, it is the most populous time zone in the world", I wonder if there would be any interest from anyone in that time zone, to help out?

**On the vast majority of days, not much diamond moderation is necessary on this site, however once in a while there may be an urgent spam attack or flag that needs addressing at 3am in UTC-4, in which case we would benefit from someone in UTC+8 where it's 3pm, to handle the flag, because *only* diamond moderators can handle flags.**

This is nothing super urgent. Most of the moderation on this site is done by community moderators rather than diamond moderators. But knowing whether or not someone in the "most populous time zone in the world" ***wants*** the job (unpaid unfortunately, that's SE's decision not mine) would be helpful!